# Accessing another database wtih SQL queries

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

I am attempting to access another database in my rails app, as well as query that database with SQL statements and return JSON.

The main database and secondary are on the same server running in MySQL. When testing to see if this would simply work as:

*The datagbase.yml file:*

```
development:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  database: onlineportal
  username: root
  password: 
  host: 127.0.0.1
  port: 3306
  socket: 

android_mobile_developement:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  database: androidchatterdatabase
  username: root
  password: 
  host: 127.0.0.1
  port: 3306
  socket:
```

*but then building out the method in the controller:*

```
class RequestsController < ApplicationController
     def getActivatedFriends
        @results = User.find_by_sql("SELECT 
                                        a.id
                                     ,  a.username
                                     ,  a.phoneNumber
                                     FROM androidchatterdatabase.users a
                                     WHERE phoneNumber in (8754444444) and
                                           removed = 0 and
                                           is_user = 1;")

        respond_to do |format|
            format.html
            format.json { render json: { friends_match: @results }}
        end         
       end
```

*and calling the route:*

```
localhost:3000/getActivatedFriends/
```

*from the routes:*

```
match '/getActivatedFriends/', to: 'requests#getActivatedFriends', via: 'get'
```

*yields the error:*

```
Missing template requests/getActivatedFriends, application/getActivatedFriends with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw, :ruby, :coffee, :jbuilder]}.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While sending the request, send it as local host:3000/getActivatedFriends.json.That way controller will respond to json request. By default it responds to html request.

Answer (score 1):

You can access another database by specifying the database name before the table, such as:

```
SELECT * FROM onlineportal.table
- or -
SELECT * FROM androidchatterdatabase.table
```

Is this what you're looking to do? If they're on the same server this syntax would work.